# Input text to a link within an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a list of links not in an iframe which refresh the iframe with different info.eg

```
href="http://www.myfav.co.uk/nf_req_grid.php?g=top_72&e=joebloggs@mail.com<? echo $email; ?>" target="iframe_c"
```

This works well, but I also need the user to input text for the g=xxxx bit that are not on the general list, which also resides outside the iframe. I have tried various methods including hidden in an input statement but only sucessfully done by re-loading the whole page which I wish to avoid.
I am sure the answer is simple but is eluding me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easiest to just rig this up with some javascript like this:

```
<input name="g" type="text" />
<button name="b" value="Refresh" />

<script>
   $(document).ready( function(){
       $('button[name="b"]').click( function() {
          var g = $('input[name="g"]').val();
          var e = '<?= $email ?>';
          var url = 'http://www.myfav.co.uk/nf_req_grid.php?g='+g+'&e='+email;
          $('#iframeId').attr('src', url);
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="ginpt"><br/>
<a href="http://www.myfav.co.uk/nf_req_grid.php?g={g}&e=joebloggs@mail.com" class="dlink" target="iframe_c">a</a><br/>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org?q={g}&e=a@a.com" class="dlink" target="iframe_c">b</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.bing.com?q={g}&e=a@a.com" class="dlink" target="iframe_c">c</a><br/>


<iframe src="" name="iframe_c"></iframe>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('.dlink').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(
      $(this).attr('href').replace('{g}',$('.ginpt').val()),
      $(this).attr('target')
    );
  })
});
</script>
```

In this example, I'm just replacing your g querystring value with a macro that'll be replaced by javascript function when they click on the anchor.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0dzassds/1/